# jQuery: creating a grid, filling an element

Tags: jquery, html, grid, fill

I'm trying to create a game using jQuery for a project, but it's advancing slow.
The issue I'm now dealing with is the following:

I have this in my html:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="board">
                <div id="gameBoard">
                <!-- some other things -->
    </div>
    <!-- some other things -->
    </div>
    <!-- some other things -->
    </div>
```

This is the css of the board:

```
#board {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(222, 184, 135, 0.5);
    position: relative;
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is **a complete grid overlay** (using jQuery) on the board. I have searched for such examples, but can't find anything, or I don't know how to fill it in here. (This is the important part for me, the part I can't seem to achieve).

Also, I only want it to stay INSIDE the board. So it MAY NOT go outside of it. How do I do that? (EDIT: used the overflow-attr, so now that's not a problem).

Thanks in advance for this complex question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay your #board should have following css to be applied to it

```
#board {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(222, 184, 135, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

then you want #gameboard to be filled entirely in to #boards, so #gameboard should have following css

```
#gameboard {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: If I do that: the #gameBoard is coming out of the rightside of the board. How can I avoid that?

EDIT: I used position: relative instead of absolute. That pretty much worked. Now, how do I do the grid?

Comment: try and add following css rule to your stylesheet     *{box-sizing:border-box}